# A variable chart axis depending on if data is present in the corresponding cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart which contains Output in percent on the y axis and days of the week on the x axis. Some days, there may be no output if production is not running that day (some weekends but not all). This causes a dip in the chart as it jumps from some output value (lets say 90%) to 0% on a day when there was not production. When there was not production, I do not want the data to be recorded in the chart.

Is there a way through chart setup, cell formulas, or vba to format the chart axis to use only the days that contain output data?

Comment: You probably don't need a scripting solution for this, which means it's likely this question would be better asked on [Superuser](https://superuser.com). Letting people know what kind of chart it is would also be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple trick in excel to hide values in charts (not all charts but quite a few). If you use #N/A the chart can ignore these values (see my table 1). It creates "gaps" where the #N/A is located as default. But you could choose to treat #N/A's as "gap", "0" or "fill gap by connect lines".

If the cell is hidden (column or row is hidden) or **filtered out**... which I did on my second table, excel ignores these values. So for my second table I only filter values, while excluding all #N/A. I would treat those 0% as #N/A for graphical purpose (dummy column...)

[image]

Some extended reading can also be found here: 
[Display empty cells, null (#N/A) values, and hidden worksheet data in a chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-empty-cells-null-n-a-values-and-hidden-worksheet-data-in-a-chart-a1ee6f0c-192f-4248-abeb-9ca49cb92274)

Comment: Wow that is a neat trick, unfortunately, my company is using an excel build which predates this feature and thus I don't have the "show #n/a as an empty cell not available" feature. I do have the treat cells empty cells as null ability, but apparently does not consider a cell containing a formula to be blank. Any work arounds for this? I like the hide ability as well although I will most likely need to build a short macro that hides rows when the data="" in the cell.

Comment: That's sad :(, then I can only think about filtering or hiding rows. I wrote a piece of code earlier today which you can likewise use or have as an starting point :) It checks for cells that are empty ("") in the range `B3:B27` and hides if that condition is true. Take care! :)

Comment: `Sub HideRowsInRange()

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("B3:B27") 'Define your range which should look for "", then loop through that range.
    If c.Value = "" Then Rows(c.Row).Hidden = True 'If my range has "" then it will hide the row.
    Next c

End Sub`